Serilog - write a single Log file every hour
I have the following .Net Core - appsetting.  It writes the log but writes multiple log files.
Like this:   How can I get write a single file every hour?  thx!!  Help!
log-2024080512_001.txt     8/5  12:25
log-2024080512_002.txt     8/5   12:19
log-2024080512.txt         8/5    12:03

**My Appsetting looks like this**

{
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": ["Serilog.Sinks.File"],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "File",
        "Args": {
          "path": "./logs/log-.txt",
          "rollingInterval": "Hour",
          "outputTemplate": "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level:u3}] {Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": ["FromLogContext", "WithMachineName", "WithProcessId", "WithThreadId"]
  }
}


The question seems is a little unclear (to me at least) - what is the exact naming you're seeing, and what is the naming you desire? (I'd tend to write the config logic in C# and then work back to the config file after I have something that does what I'm after)

I expect to see a single file each hour.  not 3

ok but the timestamps you provide seem conflicting/ambiguous to me (and are they created or last updated etc)? how did they end up that way?. What naming would you expect/prefer? My wild guess is that you had rolling based on file size limit going on at some point that caused the premature roll-over, but that doesnt make sense either. There subtleties in this space, so you need to be very clear on what you want exactly (and it may or may not be possible to get exactly what you desire with Serilog Sinks File)
